# Monotone Convergence theorem (Measure theory,Royden Real analysis).

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was reading the proof of monotone convergence theorem, I understood the proof except the ones marked in blue, I know that $\liminf \leq \limsup$, but how they arrive at equality using this, I am unable to understand?

[image]

Using $\liminf \leq \limsup$ , how we proceed to prove the equality!

Comment: I think as $\int_{E}f_{n} \leq \int_{E}f  \implies liminf\int_{E}f_{n} \leq \int_{E}f $ ??

Comment: Actually it's the other way around: $liminf \le limsup$.

Comment: will edit , ok then??

Comment: ok,then $liminf\int_{E}f_{n} \leq limsup\int_{E}f_{n} \leq \int_{E}f $ and hence follows right, i made mistake in the inequality , ok, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fatou says

$\tag1 \liminf_n\int f_n\ge \int f.$

On the other hand $\int f_n\le \int f,\ $ so

$\tag2 \limsup_n\int f_n\le \int f.$

Combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get

$\tag3 \limsup\int f_n\le \int f\le \liminf_n\int f_n, $

and this implies immediately that $\lim_n\int f_n$ exists and is equal to $\int f.$

Comment: I think the inequality is incorrect regarding liminf and limsup?

Comment: The point is that since he showed $\limsup\le \liminf$, this means that the $\lim $ itself  exists and is equal to $\int f$.

Comment: First of all $\liminf \leq \limsup $!!

Comment: Yes and thus the fact that Royden shows that $\limsup\le \liminf$  means equality holds.